# Troubles with NLTK bigram finder

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a text file labeled "all.txt" It contains a regular english paragraph

For some reason when I run this code:

```
    import nltk
    from nltk.collocations import *
    bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
    trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()

    # change this to read in your data                                                                                                                                                   
    finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(('all.txt'))

    # only bigrams that appear 3+ times                                                                                                                                                  
    #finder.apply_freq_filter(3)                                                                                                                                                         

    # return the 10 n-grams with the highest PMI                                                                                                                                         
    print finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 10)
```

I get the following result:

```
       [('.', 't'), ('a', 'l'), ('l', '.'), ('t', 'x'), ('x', 't')]
```

What am I doing wrong, since I am only getting letters? I am looking for words not letters!

Here is an example of what is in "all.txt", so you get an idea of what is being processed:
"and it 's not just democrats who oppose this plan .  americans across the country have expressed their opposition to this plan .my democratic colleagues and i have a better plan that will strengthen the ethics rules to improve congressional accountability and to make sure that legislation is properly considered .  the republican plan fails to close a loophole that allows legislation to be considered before members have read it ."

Comment: upvote for uncommented downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that you aren't actually reading the file in, you're just passing a string containing the file path to the function, and the second problem is that you need to use a tokenizer, first. To resolve the second problem:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(word_tokenize("This is a test sentence"))
print finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 10)
```

Yields `[('This', 'is'), ('a', 'test'), ('is', 'a'), ('test', 'sentence')]`

Note that you may want to use a different tokenizer--the tokenize package documentation will explain more about the various options.

In the case of the first, you can use something like:

```
with open('all.txt', 'r') as data_file:
    finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(word_tokenize(data_file.read())
```